# Validating Edit text input with regex

Tags: android

I want to validate my edit text input for the String like "3.0 - 2.0 = 1.0".
how can i do this by using regex?

Comment: What do you want to validate exactly, that the string is like: a number, a operator, a number, an equal character and a number?

Comment: It depends on for what purpose you are validating?

Comment: @Eselfar Yes. I want to validate for this string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android.text.TextWatcher` on your TextView `textview.addTextChangedListener(...)`

and on method

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //apply your regex here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String c = //content of the EditText;
c.matches("^\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*-\\s*\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*=\\s*\\d+\\.\\d+$");
```

`\\d` is a number
`\\s` a whitespace (with this regex the whitespace is no mandatory. Use '+' or {1} instead of '*' if needed).
This regex test if the format is:

- one number or more
- a '.'
- one number or more
- 0 or more whitespace
- a '-'
- 0 or more whitespace
- one number or more
- a '.'
- one number or more
- a '='
- 0 or more whitespace
- one number or more
- a '.'
- one number or more

So you can validate anything like:

- "15.0 + 125.12 = 140.12" -
- "415.0+125.12=540.12"
- "15.10  +125.1=    140.11"